# Linux- command line - How to grep smt of a hidden file inside a directory of all directories

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

I am in a directory that has let's say 100 directories (and nothing else) and each of them has another 50 directories (and nothing else) and each of the directory(of the 50) has some hidden files. All the 50 dirs have the same name for the hidden file.

How can I grep something in the hidden file?

Example:

```
grep "Killed" .log
```

(the .log file is inside each of the 50 dirs; but I am in the root of the 100 dirs)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -r --include=.log 'Killed'
```

This starts a recursive `grep` in your current directory including only files matching the name `.log`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit ambiguous.  Do you have multiple "hidden" files, and you only want to search for a string in files with a particular name, or do you want to search for the string in all of the files?  Either way, it's pretty trivial:

```
find /root/dir -type f -exec grep pattern {} \;  # Search all files
find /root/dir -type f -name '*.log' -exec grep pattern {} \; # Search only in files with names matching '*.log'
```

You'll often want to add a `-H` (or specify /dev/null as a second argument) to the invocation of `grep` to see filenames.

Comment: You may want to also add `-mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3` to `find` to further limit the search (assuming that the OP's directory tree may extend beyond what he described).